# Trouble on repairing EFI partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

[Partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nunjQ.png)

I`m trying to repair the EFI partition while reinstaling Ubuntu. I created the sda1 partition (FAT32, "boot" flag and mount at /boot/efi), but my notebook does not recognize the HD as a boot option anymore. I got the message "reboot and select proper boot device". What should I do?

Comment: The presence of an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is not sufficient to make a computer bootable; it *must* contain a boot loader, and in most cases that boot loader must be referenced by an NVRAM entry. You haven't described enough of what you did to know what else you must do. Normally Ubuntu will install GRUB to the ESP and create the NVRAM entry during OS installation, but it's not clear how you installed or if you've messed with the ESP after installing the OS.